# Logic to do a vertical carousel for images with different height

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, vertical-alignment

I'm doing my own vertical jquery carousel ... imgs are going from a database and i don't know these height then i need to know is there some logic to calc the height of container?

Comment: What have you tried? Welcome to SO, a programming community that is glad to assist you in any of your ventures, however we will not provide code to those who do not show their own attempts.

Comment: @Matt Clark, well i did my own horizontal carousel and i calc the width of container doing count items*these width then i get the width of container but now i'm doing a vertical carousel and in this case i don't know the height of these imgs cuz them can have differents heights and i would like to know how to calc it then cuz i don't know the height of imgs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is say the container has a div of class container
   `var container=$("div.container")`
the height is given by 
   `container.height();`

Comment: but i think it will not work if i call it on domReady cuz these imgs will not be loaded then it will give me the wrong value, isn't?